# Firebase real time database worldwide available

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Quick question, can't seem to find the answer, altough I am pretty sure it is an easy one. When creating a real time database in Firebase and implementing it in my app. Can I access the data worldwide? Or is it bound to a region? Say I register the database in the US and I go to Europe. Can I still access all my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Database location has nothing to do with accessibility of data. It just specifies where you data will be stored.

*To reduce latency and increase availability, store your data close to the users and services that need it.*

That being said you can access your project and database as long as you have internet connectivity (and you clients can access it if they pass the security rules).